# Declaration of an array in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have in a Excel field (created by someone) a formula containing an Array:
 `=PERCENTILE(Scale1, 0.5)`.
I need to expand this array to other fields.

Usually an Array is a range like `A1:C52`, so expanding it means modifying the formula to, let's say **`A1:C152`**.

But this "Scale1", even if I can see its border in a blue color, I can't modify its range.

I tried to search where this "Scale1" is defined, but without success. Does somebody know how to modify it?

(I can't just replace "Scale1" with A1:C152, because "Scale1" is used in multiple places...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like *somone* has used names. You can modify them interactively in the UI:

- Go to the *Formulas* tab/ribbon
- Click on *Name Manager*
- Select *Scale1*
- Change the range in the text field at the bottom
- Click the *Close* button

(In Excel 2003, a similar dialog can be opened with "Name > Define..." (in the *Insert* menu).

or via VBA:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names("Scale1").RefersTo = "Table1!$A$1:$C$152"
```

Comment: I searched in Excel formulas and in the VBA project code for "Scale1" but found nothing... where should I search to replace 54=>152 ?

Comment: Now I'm confused. I understood that several formulas contain "Scale1". But now you're saying you can't find it. So where exactly in Excel do you see "Scale1"?

Comment: I mean, I can find its (Scale1) usage in excel field formulas, but not its "definition".

Comment: but in the code really is used code like `ActiveWorkbook.Names("NN").RefersToRange`, but i couldn't find "Names("Scale1")"

Comment: See addition for Excel 2003 above. It seems to me that you aren't interested in VBA solution. If so, please change the title and the tags of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007/2010, you can open the xlsx document's XML contents.  Look for 'Scale1' this way.  To do this in code, use the [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/default.aspx) APIs.

Retrieving Excel cell values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332058%28office.12%29.aspx

Similar question on recalculating formulas: [OpenXML SDK: Make Excel recalculate formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668643/openxml-sdk-make-excel-recalculate-formula)

Finally, if you need to do this in VBA, I found this article on editing elements, but have not tried this: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007FileFormat02.asp

For Excel 2003, you can install the [Compatibility Pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint-2007-file-formats-HA010168676.aspx) which will allow Office 2003 to open, edit, save, and create files using the Open XML Formats new to the 2007 Microsoft Office system.

Comment: I added a link above to allow Excel 2003 to work with 2007/2010 files.  Try this to see if you can see the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2003, the names manager is at Insert|Name|Define.