# Enter Data Into Excel and Print it Out With Out Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Service C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I wantted to insert data an excel after that read calculated values.But this program will work on microsoft server.So Interop service not quite well for that.I looked OleDb ant another services but none of them cant calculate.

I will get values than put excel after calculation i get calculated values to my program.

I did this situation with interop but there is problem with windows server.Can i do this with different style?

Comment: [ClosedXml ?](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)

Comment: You want excel to calculate values for you, but you don't want to run excel? Pick one.

Comment: You might want to check this: https://github.com/eiceblue/Spire.XLS-for-.NET/blob/master/CS-Examples/12_Formulas/CalculateFormulas.cs

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes i want excel to calculate.Becasue i will run the program on microsoft server so exactly i dont want run  excel.

Comment: @Max i guess i tried it

Comment: @Dheeraj Malik i will take a look thank you

Comment: @DheerajMalik i looked but there is 17 sheet formula on my excel. my company dont want to share excel file to employees.They want just front face design,so i will send values excel excel will calculate and i will read it back on microsoft server.

Comment: Building a new system around an excel spreadsheet is a really bad idea. The best option is to use the spreadsheet as a specification and source of unit tests. Then reimplement everything.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) which allows recalculating sheets by using the following code:

```
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
```

See [OpenXML SDK: Make Excel recalculate formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668643/openxml-sdk-make-excel-recalculate-formula) for more information.

Also you may consider using third-party components designed for the server-side execution.